# Python: using multiprocessing on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I want to use `multiprocessing` on a large dataset to find the distance between two gps points. I constructed a test set, but I have been unable to get `multiprocessing` to work on this set.

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import vincenty
from itertools import combinations
import multiprocessing as mp

df = pd.DataFrame({'ser_no': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
                'co_nm': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc', 'cc'],
                'lat': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                'lon': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]})



def calc_dist(x):
    return pd.DataFrame(
               [ [grp,
                  df.loc[c[0]].ser_no,
                  df.loc[c[1]].ser_no,
                  vincenty(df.loc[c[0], x], 
                           df.loc[c[1], x])
                 ]
                 for grp,lst in df.groupby('co_nm').groups.items()
                 for c in combinations(lst, 2)
               ],
               columns=['co_nm','machineA','machineB','distance'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count() - 1))
    pool.map(calc_dist, ['lat','lon'])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I am using Python 2.7.11 and Ipython 4.1.2 with Anaconda 2.5.0 64-bit on Windows7 Professional when this error occurs.

> runfile('C:/.../Desktop/multiprocessing test.py', wdir='C:/.../Desktop')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/.../Desktop/multiprocessing test.py', wdir='C:/.../Desktop')
>
> File "C:...\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:...\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "C:/..../multiprocessing test.py", line 33, in 
>       pool.map(calc_dist, ['lat','lon'])
>
> File "C:...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
>       return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
>
> File "C:...\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
>       raise self._value
>
> TypeError: Failed to create Point instance from 1.

```
def get(self, timeout=None):
    self.wait(timeout)
    if not self._ready:
        raise TimeoutError
    if self._success:
        return self._value
    else:
        raise self._value
```

Comment: With your last edit, it works fine on my machine... Ubuntu 14.04, python2.7

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: Can you post the complete stack strace in your question too, please?

Comment: I tried with python3 and now I can reproduce your error

Comment: @salomonderossi I am using iPython 4.1.2

Comment: Hmm.. Strange, that python2 works fine and python3 makes such trouble. The complete stack strace looks different on my machine. Maybe this helps you  http://pastebin.com/ZuY0h5fM

Comment: @salomonderossi I cannot view the trace. pastebin is blocked by my work.

Comment: @dustin what operating system are you on?

Comment: @piRSquared I using Windows7

Comment: I'm not claiming to know for sure, but I've had interesting things happen when using mp on windows.  I remember (vaguely) that I had to put my worker function in a separate module.  Try putting you "calc_dist" function in a different file and importing it.  I don't know if that'll fix your problem, but it should be easy enough to try.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### What's wrong

This line from your code:

```
pool.map(calc_dist, ['lat','lon'])
```

spawns 2 processes - one runs `calc_dist('lat')` and the other runs `calc_dist('lon')`. Compare the first example in [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html). (Basically, `pool.map(f, [1,2,3])` calls `f` three times with arguments given in the list that follows: `f(1)`, `f(2)`, and `f(3)`.) If I'm not mistaken, your function `calc_dist` can only be called `calc_dist('lat', 'lon')`. And it doesn't allow for parallel processing.

### **Solution**

I believe you want to split the work between processes, probably sending each tuple `(grp, lst)` to a separate process. The following code does exactly that.

First, let's prepare for splitting:

```
grp_lst_args = list(df.groupby('co_nm').groups.items())

print(grp_lst_args)
[('aa', [0, 1, 2]), ('cc', [7, 8, 9]), ('bb', [3, 4, 5, 6])]
```

We'll send each of these tuples (here, there are three of them) as an argument to a function in a separate process. We need to rewrite the function, let's call it `calc_dist2`. For convenience, it's argument is a tuple as in `calc_dist2(('aa',[0,1,2]))`

```
def calc_dist2(arg):
    grp, lst = arg
    return pd.DataFrame(
               [ [grp,
                  df.loc[c[0]].ser_no,
                  df.loc[c[1]].ser_no,
                  vincenty(df.loc[c[0], ['lat','lon']], 
                           df.loc[c[1], ['lat','lon']])
                 ]
                 for c in combinations(lst, 2)
               ],
               columns=['co_nm','machineA','machineB','distance'])
```

And now comes the multiprocessing:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count() - 1))
results = pool.map(calc_dist2, grp_lst_args)
pool.close()
pool.join()

results_df = pd.concat(results)
```

`results` is a list of results (here data frames) of calls `calc_dist2((grp,lst))` for `(grp,lst)` in `grp_lst_args`. Elements of `results` are later concatenated to one data frame.

```
print(results_df)
  co_nm  machineA  machineB          distance
0    aa         1         2  156.876149391 km
1    aa         1         3  313.705445447 km
2    aa         2         3  156.829329105 km
0    cc         8         9  156.060165391 km
1    cc         8         0  311.910998169 km
2    cc         9         0  155.851498134 km
0    bb         4         5  156.665641837 km
1    bb         4         6  313.214333025 km
2    bb         4         7  469.622535339 km
3    bb         5         6  156.548897414 km
4    bb         5         7  312.957597466 km
5    bb         6         7   156.40899677 km
```

BTW, In Python 3 we could use a `with` construction:

```
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(calc_dist2, grp_lst_args)
```

**Update**

I tested this code only on linux. On linux, the read only data frame `df` can be accessed by child processes and is not copied to their memory space, but I'm not sure how it exactly works on Windows. You may consider splitting `df` into chunks (grouped by `co_nm`) and sending these chunks as arguments to some other version of `calc_dist`.

Answer (score 13):

I wrote a package to use apply methods on Series, DataFrames and GroupByDataFrames on multiple cores. It makes it very easy to do multiprocessing in Pandas.

You can check the documentation at https://github.com/akhtarshahnawaz/multiprocesspandas

You can also install the package directly using pip

```
pip install multiprocesspandas
```

Then doing multiprocessing is as simple as importing the package as

```
from multiprocesspandas import applyparallel
```

and then using applyparallel instead of apply like

```
def func(x):
    import pandas as pd
    return pd.Series([x['C'].mean()])

df.groupby(["A","B"]).apply_parallel(func, num_processes=30)
```

Comment: This package works like a charm on my MacBook. Thanks.

Comment: This package is perfect for Windows users! Would be amazing if it had progressbar!

Answer (score 2):

Strange. It seems to work under python2 but not python3.

This is a minimal modified version to print the output:

```py
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import vincenty
from itertools import combinations
import multiprocessing as mp

df = pd.DataFrame({'ser_no': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
                'co_nm': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc', 'cc'],
                'lat': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                'lon': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]})



def calc_dist(x):
    ret =  pd.DataFrame(
               [ [grp,
                  df.loc[c[0]].ser_no,
                  df.loc[c[1]].ser_no,
                  vincenty(df.loc[c[0], x],
                           df.loc[c[1], x])
                 ]
                 for grp,lst in df.groupby('co_nm').groups.items()
                 for c in combinations(lst, 2)
               ],
               columns=['co_nm','machineA','machineB','distance'])
    print(ret)
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count() - 1))
    pool.map(calc_dist, ['lat','lon'])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

And this is the output from python2

```
0     aa         1         2  110.723608682 km
1     aa         1         3  221.460709525 km
2     aa         2         3  110.737100843 km
3     cc         8         9  110.827576495 km
4     cc         8         0  221.671650552 km
   co_nm  machineA  machineB          distance
5     cc         9         0  110.844074057 km
0     aa         1         2  110.575064814 km
1     aa         1         3  221.151481337 km
6     bb         4         5  110.765515243 km
2     aa         2         3  110.576416524 km
7     bb         4         6    221.5459187 km
3     cc         8         9  110.598565514 km
4     cc         8         0  221.203121352 km
8     bb         4         7  332.341640771 km
5     cc         9         0  110.604555838 km
6     bb         4         5   110.58113908 km
9     bb         5         6  110.780403457 km
7     bb         4         6  221.165643396 km
10    bb         5         7  221.576125528 km
8     bb         4         7  331.754177186 km
9     bb         5         6  110.584504316 km
10    bb         5         7  221.173038106 km
11    bb         6         7  110.795722071 km
11    bb         6         7   110.58853379 km
```

And this the stack trace from python3

```
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/geopy/point.py", line 123, in __new__
    seq = iter(arg)
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "gps.py", line 29, in calc_dist
    for grp, lst in df.groupby('co_nm').groups.items()
  File "gps.py", line 30, in <listcomp>
    for c in combinations(lst, 2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/geopy/distance.py", line 322, in __init__
    super(vincenty, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/geopy/distance.py", line 115, in __init__
    kilometers += self.measure(a, b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/geopy/distance.py", line 342, in measure
    a, b = Point(a), Point(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/geopy/point.py", line 126, in __new__
    "Failed to create Point instance from %r." % (arg,)
TypeError: Failed to create Point instance from 8.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps.py", line 38, in <module>
    pool.map(calc_dist, ['lat', 'lon'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: Failed to create Point instance from 8.
```

I know this is not the answer, but maybe it helps...

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Python2, Python3, Ipython 4.1.2

Comment: Line 599 in pool.py is a different issues then line 567 I am getting with Python 2.7.11 with IPython 4.1.2

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that Python multiprocessing are inconvenient for large data. Using multiprocessing with large DataFrame, you can only use a `Manager` and its `Namespace` to share this data across multiple processes, otherwise your memory consumption will be huge. The performance can be significantly worse than the single-process version.

For accelerating the calculation on Pandas, I prefer using `numba`. Just create a function like

```py
@numba.jit
def calc_dist(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

and use `df.apply(calc_dist)`.