# Python - pool.map_async pass params to the function

Tags: python, database, multithreading, dataframe, io

I'm getting data into a list of `pandas.Dataframe`.
Then I need to send this data to a DB. It tool ~2min per iteration.

So I wanted to know of parallel processing is a good idea ? (no lock issue or something ?)

So I wanted to implement it from :

```
for df in df_list:
    # Send a DF's batch to the DB
    print('Sending DF\'s data to DB')
    df.to_sql('ga_canaux', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    db.check_data()
```

To something I find about multiprocessing:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    results = pool.map_async(df.to_sql(???), df_list)
    results.wait()
```

How can I pass the params I need in `df.to_sql` with `map_async` ?

EDIT :

I try something to pass N arguments like :

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    args = ((df, engine, db) for df in df_list)
    results = pool.map(multiproc, args)
    results.wait()
```

but I get the error `TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects`

EDIT2:

I changed a bit the way I'm doing `mp` and it's kinda work (179s vs 732s with the same sample dataset). But I'm facing an error when I try to read from the DB inside the pool.

```
# Connect to the remote DB
global DB
DB = Database()
global ENGINE
ENGINE = DB.connect()

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() - 1)
pool.map(multiproc, df_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()

def multiproc(df):
    print('Sending DF\'s data to DB')
    df.to_sql('ga_canaux', ENGINE, if_exists='append', index=False)
    DB.check_data() // HERE
```

Error :

```
(psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
 [SQL: 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ga_canaux'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

EDIT 3
When I try a on a bigger sample I got a DB timeout : `psycopg2.DatabaseError: SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out`

Comment: The params to `df.to_sql(...` are not passed with `.map_async(...`, you define it inside of `def my_function_to_sql`. Change to `.map_async(my_function_to_sql, df_list)`. **Note:** All your `dataframe` are going to be `pickeld`, that needs **time** and **memory** consumption.

Comment: Yep I made a function already but I can pass only one argument to it, the iterable values.

Check my edit.

Also what do your mean by `pickeld` ?

Comment: `pickled` means `serialisation` of data passed to or from a process. Your error indicats that you want to use **not pickable objects**. At this point you are **off**. *"can pass only one argument to it"*: Your `args` looks ok, but useless, as you passing for all `df` the same `engine` and `db`.

Comment: Same `engine` and `db` yes. Ok for `pickled`, it's been few weeks I code in python and I didn't know this word before.

Comment: Read [using-multiprocessing-on-a-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794433/python-using-multiprocessing-on-a-pandas-dataframe) to get some ideas.

Comment: Thank you that's help @stovfl. I use global for the DB and ENGINE variable and change the a bit the way I'm doing mp. Still facing a small issue.

Comment: The error means *connection being dropped, or not being able to connect to the database*. Verify if your DB driver and DB itself allow **multiple init/connect**. Worth a try, move `DB =...` and `ENGINE=...` to `def multiproc(...`