# Optimizing the runtime for cleaning n-grams

Tags: python, optimization, nlp, multiprocessing

---

I am trying to `clean` my `n-grams` obtained from the text column. I also have 2 list of `stopwords` I want to remove but only at specific places(when it occurs as a first word in the n-gram or occurs as a last word in the n-gram) and I am also looking to `remove` my n-grams which contain only `numbers or %`. The following code takes over 10 minutes to process around a million n-grams.

```
def clean_ngram(ng):
    if 'percent' in ng:
        ng = ng.replace('percent', '%')
    if 'point' in ng:
        ng = ng.replace('point', '.')
    if ng.split(' ')[0] not in stopwords['First'].dropna().values \
        and ng.split(' ')[-1] not in stopwords['Last '].dropna().values \
          and (bool(re.match(r"^[0-9.% ]+$", ng)) == False):
              return ng

df['Word'] = df['Word'].apply(lambda x: clean_ngram(x))
```

I have also tried multiprocessing but I had to terminate the process after 30 minutes as it was still running. The following is the code for the same:

```
p = Pool(processes=2)
df['Word'] = p.map(clean_ngram, df['Word'])
p.close()
p.join()
```

Is there any way I can optimize my code for a considerably less run-time? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794433/python-using-multiprocessing-on-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I am not sure how many stopwords you have in stopwords['First'] and stopwords['Last '], but generally, I would run .dropna() each time when ngram is analyzed, and I also wouldnt use pandas series for checking if word is present in it. I think that it could help to use two python sets (instead of lists/pd.series), that would be passed as two new arguments to clean_ngram, like def clean_ngram(ng,set_of_first_stopwords,set_of_last_stopwords)

Comment: @JanMusil But I am using the pandas numpy(.values) attribute to convert in into a numpy array and then checking if a word is in it. Dont you think it should be fast as compared to sets?

Comment: Of course it depends on your data, but I added an answer, where I show example with random data, and its much faster when you converts data to set at the beginning than converting pandas Series to numpy when checking each ngram.

Comment: @JanMusil Yes you were right. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In following code, I created random stopwords (containing also some nans) and random words. Then Using functions that I created, I checked how long it take to run when stopwords is pandas Series converted to numpy as you do it in your code. Also I checked how long it takes when stopwords is converted to simple python set of similar length.

As you can see from output it was almost **2000 times faster, when using set**.

Therefore I recommend you not to use `not in stopwords['First'].dropna().values`, but convert `stopwords['First'].dropna().values` to set (using `stopwords_first = set(stopwords['First'].dropna().values)`), then you just do `not in stopwords_first`. Note that the conversion to set must be done outside the function (so that you don't convert stopwords each time you check another ngram)

This is just an example, and your speed will be highly depending on your data, but I believe it can help.

```
#first generate random 450 stopwords + 50 nans
>>> stopwords = np.array(['word_num'+str(i) for i in range(450)]+[np.nan for _ in range(50)])

#shuffle the stopwords and print some of them
>>> stopwords = pd.Series(stopwords).sample(frac=1)
>>> stopwords
304    word_num304
84      word_num84
215    word_num215
438    word_num438
276    word_num276
          ...     
217    word_num217
280    word_num280
69      word_num69
365    word_num365
404    word_num404
Length: 500, dtype: object

#generate random words to be checked if they are in stopwords
>>> ngrams = ['word_num{}'.format(int(np.random.rand()*1000)) for _ in range(20000)]
>>> ngrams = np.array(ngrams)
>>> ngrams
array(['word_num642', 'word_num729', 'word_num901', ..., 'word_num940',
       'word_num616', 'word_num58'], dtype='<U11')

#define function that checks words presence in stopwords pd.Series (same way as you did)
#this function returns also time it took to run
>>> def check_ngrams_Series(ngrams,stopwords):
...     func = lambda ng: ng in stopwords.dropna().values
...     time_begin = time()
...     result = list(map(func,ngrams))
...     time_end = time()
...     return np.array(result), time_end-time_begin

#define function that checks words presence in stopwords converted to set
#this function returns also time it took to run
>>> def check_ngrams_set(ngrams,stopwords):
...     func = lambda ng: ng in stopwords
...     time_begin = time()
...     result = list(map(func,ngrams))
...     time_end = time()
...     return np.array(result), time_end-time_begin

#try to run both functions
>>> series_out = check_ngrams_Series(ngrams,stopwords)
>>> sets_out = check_ngrams_set(ngrams,set(stopwords))

#checks their first output (words presence in stopwords) is same
>>> np.all(sets_out[0] == series_out[0])
True

#show how long it took to function that uses set to run
>>> sets_out[1]
0.008014917373657227

#show how long it took to function that uses pd.Series to run
>>> series_out[1]
15.30849814414978
```