# pandas groupby apply numpy.polyfit to tens of thousands of groups quickly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For monthly records of some count `n` for a given set of groups, I'd like to fit a basic, order-1 regression line each year's results, basically calculating how much the count changed across the year for each group. The issue is the size of the data – with tens of thousands of groups across several years, my pandas groupby - apply routine is very, very slow. My contrived workflow is shown below:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_letters
from itertools import product

''' Tries to fit line, otherwise returns nulls '''
def try_polyfit(x, y, deg=1):
    try:
        return np.polyfit(x, y, deg)
    except:
        return (np.nan,) * (deg + 1)

n = 25000000
date_range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2020-12-01', freq = 'MS')
group_a_reference = [''.join(g) for g in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)]
group_b_reference = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'group_a': np.random.choice(group_a_reference, n),
        'group_b': np.random.choice(group_b_reference, n),
        'date': np.random.choice(date_range, n),
        'n': np.random.randint(0, 250000, n),
    }
).sort_values('group_a group_b date'.split())
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df.drop_duplicates('group_a group_b date year'.split(), inplace=True)

# Lots of group_a - group_b - year combinations here
df[['group_a', 'group_b', 'year']].drop_duplicates().shape

df.groupby(['group_a', 'group_b', 'year']).apply(lambda x: try_polyfit(range(len(x)), x['n']))
```

Any ideas about how best to speed this up? I know `apply` is generally frowned upon, but I haven't figured out a better way of doing this row-wise aggregation.

Comment: no way to vectorise this AFAIK. You might get better performance with Dask/Ray/Modin since this looks an [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem. (Incidentally explicit iteration in bare Python `for g in grpby.groups: try_polyfit(range(len(g)), g['n])` would be slightly faster, but probably not by much.)

Comment: Perhaps. I just tried using `multiprocessing.Pool` based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36851214/5015569), and the length of time increased by about 400%, so we're off to a good start...