# Pandas Dataframe to Excel Conversion with parallel processing

Tags: python, dataframe, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing and parallel processing in python. I'm trying to export a very large dataframe to an xlsx excel sheet with multiprocessing.

Is there a way to convert this df to a excel with multiple processes? What am I doing wrong?

I've tried openpyxl and xlsxwriter as well and they both seem to operate sequentially, not parallely. The code I've written does not speed up the conversion at all.

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def save_to_excel(df):
    df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)

merged_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(173000, 82))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
    pool.apply(save_to_excel, args=(merged_df,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The performance is similar to using:
`df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)`
which is taking around 206 seconds on my system.

Update:
The dataframe is colorized and contains about a million rows, so the problem requires I export it in "xlsx" format to retain the colors. Here's a sample code that was used to color the df:

```
def _color_red_or_green(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0.5 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(_color_red_or_green)
               f"WHERE (e.{column} <> e2.{column_name}) OR (e.{column} IS NULL AND e2.{column_name} IS NOT NULL) OR (e.{column} IS NOT NULL AND e2.{column_name} IS NULL) UNION "
```

Comment: Please check this related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794433/python-using-multiprocessing-on-a-pandas-dataframe 

Also, I would recommend checking this [Dask][1] Library also. This is very powerful, easy to use parallel DataFrame

  [1]: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html

Comment: @MadihaKhalid Thank you. I am quiet new to this. The related question seems to be doing something else with columns. Could you please explain what was done there and how can I use to for my problem? Thank you

Comment: Note that I would not assume you can write to a single Excel file in parallel - this sounds unlikely.  Rather, you would probably need to write several excel files in parallel, then combine them - or some other composition of a parallel processing solution.